# Enable HSTS header in API Gateway WSO2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

Currently I have followed the instruction in WSO2 [Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Securing+Carbon+Applications) to enable HSTS headers. 
I have done the required config changes to *jaggery.conf* aslo. However, still i'm not seeing the HSTS header. 

Have I missed anything ?

EDIT: Is anything preventing this from happening ?

Comment: What is the API Manager version you are using?

Comment: APIM-2.2.0 and not a cluster